# How can union-find algorithm be used with "real" data

Tags: data-structures, modelling, union-find

In the beginning of the Princeton algorithms course the Dynamic connectivity problem is presented (quick-find, quick-union). Here is how it's described:

> The input is a sequence of pairs of integers, where each integer
>   represents an object of some type and we are to interpret the pair p q
>   as meaning “p is connected to q.” We assume that “is connected to” is
>   an equivalence relation, which means that it is
>
> - Reflexive : p is
>     connected to p.
> - Symmetric : If p is connected to q, then q is
>     connected to p.
> - Transitive : If p is connected to q and q is
>     connected to r, then p is connected to r.

And it has one simple implementation called `quick-find`:

> One approach is to maintain the invariant that p and q are connected
>   if and only if id[p] is equal to id[q]. In other words, all sites in a
>   component must have the same value in id[].This method is called
>   quick-find because find(p) just returns id[p], which immediately
>   implies that connected(p, q) reduces to just the test id[p] == id[q]
>   and returns true if and only if p and q are in the same component...To
>   combine the two components into one, we have to make all of the id[]
>   entries corresponding to both sets of sites the same value, as shown
>   in the example at right.

My question is how can this be used for real objects? It works for integers, but what if I need to know whether the object `A` is connected to the object `B`, not if `3` is connected to `5`? One solution I can think of is to have an array of objects where each object's index in the array corresponds to the index of the array used for connectivity. For example:

```
   1   2   3   4   5
[ { } { } {A} { } {B} ]   <---- real data

   1   2   3   4   5
[  1   2   3   4   3 ]    <---- connections (3 and 5 have the same group id 3)
```

Is that how it's applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: indirection.

For instance, each object could have a field that contains an index into the `id` array.

Or, you could use pointers.  Standard union-find data structures often use pointers instead of integers/indices/arrays.  Thus, each object has a pointer to another object in the same equivalence class.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure or other standard presentations of union-find data structures.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which union-find implementation you are talking about. On the abstract level, all is good; in the first quote, the authors already state that integers represent arbitrary objects!

In OOP-speak, as long as your objects have unique integer identifiers, you can immediately apply the material. In many languages, object identity will suffice.

In implementations, a union-find data structure may define an internal element wrapper (as lists and trees do as well), that is something like:

```c
struct Element<T> {
    id: Int
    value: T
}
```

You would use `id` for managing the union-find business, and all `get`-style operations would return (sets of) `value`s.

That all said, none if this changes the *concepts*; they carry over to all countable (well, recursively enumerable, I guess) sets/types. That's why algorithms textbooks typically only deal with integers: it makes for simpler notation (and code).